# Find common pairs in a column based on overlapping entries in another column grouped on it

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I need some help with a query. Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
+------+------+
|userid|songid|
+------+------+
|     1|     a|
|     1|     b|
|     1|     c|
|     2|     a|
|     2|     d|
|     3|     c|
|     4|     e|
|     4|     d|
|     5|     b|
+------+------+
```

I want to return a data frame which has `userid` pairs that have atleast one `songid` in common. It would look like this for the dataframe above:

```
+------+------+
|userid|friendid|
+------+------+
|     1|     2|
|     1|     3|
|     1|     5|
|     2|     4|
+------+------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You should add the expected output to make the question clearer and get better help.

Comment: You also forgot to show what you've tried / thinked about so far :)

Comment: @baitmbarek I thought of applying collect_set to songids after grouping them by userid. Then I thought I could apply pairwise array_intersect to these sets for all rows in the dataframe. Unfortunately this is where my knowledge of PySpark ends. Any help on how I could apply this kind of pairwise operation between all rows and then collect the results back as a dataframe would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @samkart won't that ust give me back the original dataframe. Did you mean something else?

Comment: right! What about self join on songids? `df.join(df.withColumnRenamed('userid','friendid'), 'songid', 'left').select('userid', 'friendid').dropDuplicates().filter(col('userid') != col('friendid'))`

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use a self `Join` :

```
data = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'),
        (2, 'a'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'c'),
        (4, 'e'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'b')
        ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["userid", "songid"])

# join on songId = songId and userid different
join_condition = (col("u1.songid") == col("u2.songid")) & (col("u1.userid") != col("u2.userid"))

df.alias("u1").join(df.alias("u2"), join_condition, "inner") \
    .select(sort_array(array(col("u1.userid"), col("u2.userid"))).alias("pairs")) \
    .distinct() \
    .select(col("pairs").getItem(0).alias("userid"), col("pairs").getItem(1).alias("friendid"))\
    .show()

+------+--------+
|userid|friendid|
+------+--------+
|     1|       3|
|     1|       5|
|     2|       4|
|     1|       2|
+------+--------+
```